# Getting name parameter of bluetooth device type variable null using flutter_blue_plus package

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, flutter-dependencies

I'm scanning devices in my flutter app using flutter_blue_plus package and I have been using the code provided by the documentation but still name parameter of BluetoothDevice type variable is always null.

```
  void startScan() {
    flutterBluePlus.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 4));
    scanSubscription = flutterBluePlus.scanResults.listen((results) {

      for (ScanResult r in results) {
        print('${r.device.name} found! rssi: ${r.rssi}');
      }

  flutterBluePlus.stopScan();
  }
```

this is the function, I have been using.

**Expected behavior:** it should return bluetooth device name.

**Actual behavior:** it returns nothing

output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqYTo.png)

do you guys have any idea about what's going wrong?